# jQuery list of links

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I have a list of links that I create dynamically according to the database objects, when I press an object I need to pass the next html page a variable.

my code is :

```
sections.forEach(sec => {
   var li = jQuery(`<a href='/dish.html'><li>${sec.sectionName}</li></a>`)
   jQuery('#sections').append(li);
     });
 jQuery('#sections').click(function() {
    //here I need to determine what link was pressed by the user.
        });


#sections is an ordered list
```

Thanks

Comment: Then what issue you are facing?

Comment: I updated my code like the button answer , now I'm not sure how to extract the text for the specific <li> that was touched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this way. I don't know which data you have to extract from `<li>`. I have extracted text contained in `<li>` I hope it may be help you.

```
var sections = [{"sectionName":"rahul"},{"sectionName":"rohit"}]; // My dummy Object

sections.forEach(sec => {
   var li = jQuery(`<a class="mylinks" href='#'><li>${sec.sectionName}</li></a>`)
            jQuery('#sections').append(li);
      });

$(document).on("click",".mylinks",function(){
  var  touched_li = $(this).find("li").text();
  alert(touched_li); // Get section name. e.g rahul
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of determining what link was pressed, you can attach action listener for your every "li" element.
BTW The is an convention of prepending "$" sign at the beginning of variable names when you assign any DOM element to it (so that's why I did it).

```
sections.forEach(sec => {
    var $li = jQuery(`<a href='/dish.html'><li>${sec.sectionName}</li></a>`);
    $li.on('click', () => {
        //here you can attach listener for each element. You can reference using:
        var $currentElement = $(this);
        //now you can operate on current anchor element.
    });

    jQuery('#sections').append($li);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to extract the text for the specific <li> that was touched.